# Exited event of Process fires if I Start a second process

Tags: wpf, process

I have this code in an application of WPF:

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
      public MainWindow()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
          var p = new Process();
          p.Exited += (o, args) =>
          {
              Debug.WriteLine($"Process exited {((Process)o).StartInfo.FileName}");
          };
          p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\temp\\Example1.xlsx";
          p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
          p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
          p.Start();
      }

      private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
          var p2 = new Process();
          p2.Exited += (o, args) =>
          {
              Debug.WriteLine($"Process exited {((Process)o).StartInfo.FileName}");
          };
          p2.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\temp\\Example2.xlsx";
          p2.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
          p2.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
          p2.Start();
      }
  }
```

First, I click the first button, and the first process started.
Then, I click the second button, and the second process started, but immediately this second process fires `Exited` event.

Why is firing the `Exited` event when start the second process?